# mean and sd with user specified conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I have transformed into following format:

```
Date         price Industry  stock
29/10/2018   3      Airline   A
28/10/2018   4      Airline   A
27/10/2018   2      Airline   A
29/10/2018   5      Bank      B
29/10/2018   3      Food      C
28/10/2018   4      Bank      B
27/10/2018   2      Bank      B
27/10/2018   6      Food      C
```

I also have inputs for Start Date , end date , industry and stock. I have created a subset  based on  user inputs with following code:

```
desc_filtered <- reactive({
c<-  dailyprice_gather %>%
  group_by(stocks) %>%
  mutate(
price_at_date = price[Date == selected_date2],
new_price = price - price_at_date)
c <- subset(c, Date>=input$dateRange[1] )
c <- subset(c, Date<=input$dateRange[2] )
c <- subset(c, Industry == input$industry2)
c <- subset(c, stocks == input$equities)
 })
```

I want to display mean and sd for user selected Industries and stocks for the specified time period. Industries and stocks are multiple selection dropdown 
I probably need to use rowMeans but not sure how to use rowMean for reactive function.

Comment: `c` is a function in R. I don't think it is a good idea to use `c` as an object, which creates a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the package **dplyr**, you can use the function `filter()` and `group_by()` to calculate price mean (and sd) by stock.

Suppose your dataset is `df`:

```
df %>%
   filter(Date >= input$dateRange[1] & Date <= input$dateRange[2]) %>%
   filter(Industry %in% input$industry_choices) %>%
   group_by(Industry, stock) %>%
   summarise(
       price_mean = mean(price),
       price_sd   = mean(sd)
   )
```

In a Shiny, inputs are considered as strings, sometimes you will need to use `group_by_()`.
For instance if user can choice the variable to group by:  `group_by_(input$grouping_choice)`

Comment: thank you for the update . How do I display summarise data on screen ?  `output$summ<-renderPrint({  
     dailyprice_gather %>%  
     filter(Date >= input$dateRange[1] & Date <= input$dateRange[2]) %>%  
     filter(Industry %in% input$industry2) %>%  
   group_by(Industry, stocks) %>%   
   summarise(   
       price_mean = mean(price),  
       price_sd   = mean(sd)  
   )  
        print(price_mean)  
      })`   Then used  `verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "summ"),` in Ui. But its giving error for Print(price_mean)

Comment: the result of your operation is a dataframe. There are several ways to print dataframe, a great one is with the library **DT**. In your **server**, use `renderDataTable()` instead of `renderPrint()` to call your reactive and transform the result in datatable object, and in your **ui** section, use `datatableOutput()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example based on what you described in your question. I think you are on the right direction. The key is to create a reactive object for the subset of the data frame. In my example, it is called `sub_dat`. We can then calculate the `mean` and `sd` based on `sub_dat` and print it with `textOutput`.

Since you are using `dplyr`, I think it is not necessary to use the base R subset function. We can achieve all the subset tasks using `filter`. The other thing is I don't think you need any `group_by` operations. But if you do, it is easy to modify my example to inlcude the `group_by` operation.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)

# Create example data frame
dailyprice_gather <- tribble(
  ~Date,   ~price, ~Industry,  ~stock,
'29/10/2018',   3,      'Airline',   'A',
'28/10/2018',   4,      'Airline',   'A',
'27/10/2018',   2,      'Airline',   'A',
'29/10/2018',   5,      'Bank',      'B',
'29/10/2018',   3,      'Food',      'C',
'28/10/2018',   4,      'Bank',      'B',
'27/10/2018',   2,      'Bank',      'B',
'27/10/2018',   6,      'Food',      'C')

# Convert to date class
dailyprice_gather <- dailyprice_gather %>% mutate(Date = dmy(Date))

# A vector to show the choices for industry
ind_choices <- sort(unique(dailyprice_gather$Industry))

# A vector to show the choices for the stock
stock_choices <- sort(unique(dailyprice_gather$stock))

# Create the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Select the date range
  dateRangeInput(inputId = "DateRange", label = "Select Date Range", 
                 start = min(dailyprice_gather$Date), 
                 end = max(dailyprice_gather$Date),
                 min = min(dailyprice_gather$Date),
                 max = max(dailyprice_gather$Date)),
  # Select the Industry
  selectInput(inputId = "Industry", label = "Select the Industry",
              choices = ind_choices, selected = ind_choices[1]),
  # Select the stock
  selectInput(inputId = "Stock", label = "Select the Stock",
              choices = stock_choices, selected = stock_choices[1]),
  # Show the mean
  h3("The Mean of Price"),
  textOutput(outputId = "MEAN"),
  # Show the standard deviation
  h3("The SD of Price"),
  textOutput(outputId = "SD")
)

# Create SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  # # Create a reactive object for subset data frame
  sub_dat <- reactive({
    dailyprice_gather %>%
      filter(Date >= input$DateRange[1], 
             Date <= input$DateRange[2],
             Industry %in% input$Industry,
             stock %in% input$Stock)
  })
  # Calculate the mean and sd based on sub_dat
  output$MEAN <- renderText({
    as.character(mean(sub_dat()$price))
  })
  output$SD <- renderText({
    as.character(sd(sub_dat()$price))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But Iam getting the following error . "Result must have length 91816, not 0" . Any idea?

Comment: It seems like you are testing your real-world dataset. Since I don't have your real-world dataset, I don't know what is going on. Please make sure the code works on your example data frame, and then try to figure out what is the differences between your example data frame and your real-world dataset.